# Set Flash Builder 4.5 mobile application VGroup background color to black

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4.5, flex-mobile, flash-builder4.5

I am creating a dummy mobile application in Flash Builder 4.5. In application code I am using a VGroup and I am adding and removing elements on rum time. Now I want to set VGroup background color to black.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't: VGroup is a layout container. It contains no graphic elements.
Read this answer about layout containers for a little more information: [Add layout to Flex UIComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309683/add-layout-to-flex-uicomponent/11309848#11309848)

The easiest solution to your problem, if you don't want to touch the VGroup, would be something like this:

```
<s:Group>
    <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0x000000" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <s:VGroup left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        <!--content goes here-->
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Group>
```

But you could also use [BorderContainer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9466e6a52123e854e5d5-8000.html) instead:

```
<s:BorderContainer backgroundColor="black">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout />
    </s:layout>

    <!--content goes here-->
</s:BorderContainer>
```

Comment: ALthough I didn't notice any performance issues when using `BorderContainer`, Adobe advises against using it in mobile applications since its a pretty heavy component.